# What sounds would this creature make?

Tags: biology, language

I am making a creature with a mouth that opens four ways, has four tongue-like things on each mouth flap and just has a giant hole in it’s mouth that goes into its stomach and lungs. It still has vocal cords and there are four tongue like things on every mouth panel.
What sounds could said creature make? I am ok if it uses sign language in some parts, and it also has a colour changing sail similar to a spinosaurus.[image]

Anatomy ^

Comment: Where are its vocal cords?

Comment: Wet, mouthy, tongue-slippy noises and lip-smacking along with gurgles and belches most likely, if the passage behind its mouths indeed only go to its stomach and not to lungs as well. Vocalization would only be possible while it belches, which would lead to a burpy language of sorts if it speaks. Ant is right though, we're basically going to need a more complete description of its anatomy, or even an image if you can manage.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot lungs existed.

Comment: that all depends on the shape of the throat and whatever sound making organ it has (larynx, syrinx, ect), it is impossible to tell from a diagram like this, sound production is a very detailed part of anatomy. basically you can have it make whatever sound you want. please note your creature way to front heavy and would fall over in real life.

Comment: We can't in any sort of grounded way answer a question, reconstructing the sounds a creature would make based on a MS paint drawing. Sure people can speculate but they will be making things up without any basis in science. Because you're asking us to make up something where every answer will be equally valid this question is too broad and opinion based for this site.

Comment: They definitely can’t produce any sounds humans can.

Comment: @John it normally uses one of its tentacle-like arms to support itself, due to it being unnecessary in most tasks. Also I only put parts of the body that I thought where necessary, it will have a way to counter the unbalance.

Comment: Just for reference, the [list of muscles](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/ladefoge/manual%20files/appendixb.pdf) in humans required for speech is quite long, control of the muscles is required necessitating separate nerves and a complex brain. These are not included in the question - do you see the difficulty of trying to answer?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. yes, I do see the difficulty. Speech is a lot more complex then I thought it was.

Comment: Even with additional details it might still come out as opinion-based - I'm thinking about my cat now, I'd never have predicted the variety of vocalisations she could make just from her physiology, and to be fair, I couldn't have predicted it from meeting other cats either, she was odd.

Comment: Why would this become opinion based ? There should be better input actually, but I regard this as a question about phonetics and vocal tract. I've put a biology/science-based answer.

Comment: Sorry about this, but I do believe your creature might be a relative of this one, and sound the same: https://i0.wp.com/comicsgrinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/don-martin-mad-magazine-june-1969.jpg?ssl=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As many sounds as we make and more, if they had the brainpower.**

Lots of animals have vocal cords and this thing does too.  Animals with mobile mouths and tongues can use them to modulate the sounds they make - all true with this beast too.  Birds have the neural circuitry to control their vocal cords and several can imitate many sounds including human speech.  If monkeys had the brains for it, they could talk too.

https://www.science.org/content/article/why-monkeys-can-t-talk-and-what-they-would-sound-if-they-could

You can have your creature make any sounds you want it to make.  Given one set of vocal cords but several sets of tongues maybe it could harmonize with itself - one rhythm but several pitches.  At the very least it could do something like [Tuvan throat singing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuvan_throat_singing) which we all need to do more.  Maybe even several overtones given its many tongues.   That would be great if this were an anime and you could actually hear it speak.

Comment: Brainpower is no problem, they are smarter then humans. But since they could make more sounds then humans, that means that the language could just involve colour and sounds!

Comment: "one rhythm but several pitches" I object to the creature being mono-rythmic, even humans can do better, _without even using the mouth_, [at least since 2014](https://youtu.be/B7njJFhxSeQ?t=26) if not earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the drawing, with a rigid vocal tract and beak, I'd expect to hear "PEEE" or "BEEE" or some other vowel, like "PAAA" or "BAAA". It could close the mouth using the lips, yielding "PEEEP" or "BEEEP".

Four words won't do for language..

**For speech, you need more variation in the voiced sounds**

Speech is very complex. I requires many different sounds.

Humans can produce different voiced sounds a-e-y-i-o etc, because they can vary the height *and* the width of the mouth. This results in two main resonance frequencies, called formants.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant

But your dinosaur-like beast can only close or open the beak vertically. Consider some extra muscles on the side of the beak, to produce variation needed in the second formant, yielding more different vowels. Another option would be to place the tongues *inside* the mouth, instead of in front.

**Whistle**

The two tongues could be worked out in more detail, so whistling would become possible. The tongues could form a narrow gateway, or be curled for this purpuse.

**Consider placing teeth and tongues *inside* to allow for more different consonants**

An important difference with human physiology: you have drawn the teeth outside the air channel, which would prevent lisping and whizzling sounds. This beast has enormous tongues in front, that could work like human lips, allowing for P and B like plosive onsets. But a little more friction would come out handy..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricative

Comment: The animal has four mouth flap things and it can open and close them how ever much they want. Since it has four mouth flap things it can open it mouth just horizontally or just vertically. I just excluded the third and forth mouth flaps so it is easier to see.

Comment: Parrots can replicate human speech, and produce a very wide range of sounds, you don't need human like oral anatomy.

Comment: Parrots can mimic vowels using their vocal chords. Also, they have means to use friction and whistling. Parrots cannot produce "b" or "p" sounds, but they can do "k" "f" and "s". They have a tongue inside the beak, with rigid parts around. In above image, I see a tongue out of place, fixed vocal tract, teeth hanging out. This is *not* a parrot. Unless you believe in speaking dragons and magic, there is no way it can articulate meaningful speech sounds imho. I worked in the research field for several years.